# warning after editing .bashrc

Tags: bash, eof, heredoc

I've just tried to add Path Variables to the .bashrc.

```
cat <<EOF >> .bashrc
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
export GRADLE_HOME=/mnt/c/Zi/gradle
export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xmx2g -Xms512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=384m"
export GRADLE_USER_HOME=/mnt/c/Z
export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH"
```

After this i get a warning:

```
-bash: warning: here-document at line 21 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

Can someone give me a hint?

Thank you,
Lisa

Answer (score 4):

The input redirection `<<EOF` means to read everything until a line with `EOF` on it, and use that as the input to the command; this is called a *here-doc*.

You're missing the `EOF` line.

```
cat <<'EOF' >> .bashrc
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
export GRADLE_HOME=/mnt/c/Zi/gradle
export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xmx2g -Xms512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=384m"
export GRADLE_USER_HOME=/mnt/c/Z
export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH"
EOF
```

Also, quote the `EOF` token in `<<'EOF'` to indicate that variables should not be expanded in the here-doc. In the last line `${JAVA_HOME}` and `$PATH` should be expanded when `.bashrc` is being loaded, not when you're adding to it.

Comment: Thank You. I've done that. No warning anymore. How can i test if it works now?

Comment: Check the end of your `.bashrc` and see if the lines were added.

Comment: FYI, it worked before -- it stopped reading at the end of the script.

Comment: echo $PATH .. to see the if it worked

Comment: @Lisella Look at the `export PATH=` line in your .bashrc. I'm pretty sure it'll be wrong, because the values of `${JAVA_HOME}` and `$PATH` will have been substituted *before* it was written to the file, rather than left literal to be substituted as the script runs. You will need to edit your .bashrc to fix this. Next time, quote the here-doc delimiter (i.e. `cat <<"EOF" >> .bashrc`) to tell the shell not to substitute variables in the here-doc.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Good catch, I've updated the answer.